# how to store multiple values in single variable in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to store multiple values in single variable(array) in postgresql stored procedure.

My query in mysql is as

```
select name from cloud_table into @cloud; // @cloud contain multiple name
```

I want to convert this query into Postgresql. how to achieve this.

Comment: How about using a temporary table instead? `select name from cloud_table into #cloud` ? Please [edit] your post and show us how that variable will be used later on.

Comment: I want to sent multiple cloud name(array) to a function for further operation

Answer (score 2):

You can store all values in an array.

Something like:

```
.... 
declare
   l_names text[];
begin
   ...
   select array_agg(name) 
       into l_names
   from cloud_table;

   -- pass the array to a function
   perform some_function(l_names);

   ...
end;
```

If you already have a function that accepts an array as a parameter and you want to pass the result of your select as an array, you can use:

```
select your_function(array(select name from cloud_table));
```